# How did Bellamy, Murphy, et. al. survive in the Ark for 6 years, when the oxygen generating system supposedly failed?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-100

In *The 100*, all of the station's population descends to Earth because the oxygen generating system of Ark had failed.

Later, Murphy, Bellamy, Monty, Raven and others went up there and spent 6 years before descending again.

How can they survive without oxygen for 6 years?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [the100.wikia.com](http://the100.wikia.com/wiki/Praimfaya), they installed oxygen scrubbers in S04E13. The relevant part from that wiki (emphasis is mine):

> "Then, Murphy, Emori, Harper, Monty, Raven, Bellamy, and Echo get onto the Ark, but Raven is low on oxygen. Murphy and Emori decide to share theirs along with everyone else. Meanwhile, **Monty instructs Bellamy to connect the oxygen scrubber to the conduits on the Ark.**"
>
> Source: http://the100.wikia.com/wiki/Praimfaya

Comment: If such an easy solution is available why did the space stations descended down to earth in the first place?

Comment: @Sonevol I don't know for sure, but I think they needed supplies from that lab (don't have a source atm, but that's how I recall from watching it a year ago or so).

Comment: I haven't seen this episode yet, but I'm inferring that teh oxygen scrubber in question came from the vessel they used to return to the Ark - it wasn't on board before.  Also, one oxygen scrubber might be good enough for 7 or 8 people, but it probably wouldn't be enough for everyone that was up there before the descent.